# How to check if the value of div id is equal to the value in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to validate a div element ID with the localstorage value. If true I need to show an error message. When I console.log the value of each they are the same, but when I console.log to compare both it returns false.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
<div id="test"></div>

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var parentEl = $('div').attr('id');
    localStorage.setItem('contentid', 'test');
    if($(parentEl) == localStorage.getItem('contentid')) {
        console.log('id === localstorage', $(parentEl) == localStorage.getItem('contentid'));
        console.log('local', localStorage.getItem('contentid'));
        console.log('id', parentEl);
        console.log('can\t go next');
    } else {
        console.log('go next');
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('div')` is a too common selector, might not return the desired. Tried instead to use `$('#test').attr('id');` ?

Comment: attr("id") will return the ID without the `#` *hash*, so let's say instead of `"#test"` will only return `"test"` - it's your job to add that missing "#". So `$(parentEl)` should be `$("#" + parentEl)` if that's the desired.

Comment: Also, important! Localstorage stores only String format type. You cannot therefore compare Object with String when doing `$("#" + parentEl) == localStorage.getItem('contentid')`  what you want is rather compare the string id like `parentEl == localStorage.getItem('contentid')`

Comment: Also, don't name something `parentEl` when it's clearly not a parent Element. It's a simple `id` string. Try not to confuse yourself when naming variables.

Comment: Issue : if($(parentEl) == localStorage.getItem('contentid'))

Comment: Same goes for: `$('button')` that's a too common selector. Use instead an ID or class like `$('#someButtonId')`

Comment: How can I remove the event on a button once clicked?
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>

Comment: First of, never use inline HTML on* handlers like `onclick="something()"` use jQuery's `.one()` method like:  `$('#someButtonId').one("click", someFunction);` that way the event will trigger only once.

Comment: It's a code that I found like that and I was asked to remove the event once the user clicked on the button. The event have some argument/parameters. I also believe the event should have been ````$('#someButtonId').one("click", someFunction);```` Now I don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, you cannot compare Object with a localStorage returned String value. so instead of `$(parentEl) == localStorage.getItem('contentid')`  use the actual ID string:

```js
if ( parentEl === localStorage.getItem('contentid') ) {
```

Why would you want to on every button click set all over again the same localStorage value to "test" ? `localStorage.setItem('contentid', 'test');` seems quite odd.

What is `var parentEl = $('div').attr('id');` ? `$('div')` can be just *any DIV* in your document. You need to select a specific one like a button's parent?

In such case use:

```js
localStorage.setItem('contentid', 'test'); // Save to LS


$('button').on('click', function(){

    const $parent = $(this).closest('.parent'); // Get button's closest DIV by class ".parent"
    if (!$parent.length) return; // No such .parent was found. Do nothing
    
    const id = $parent.attr("id");
    const idLS = localStorage.contentid;
    
    if(id === idLS) {
      console.log("Parent ID is: 'test'");
    } else {
      console.log(`Parent ID is: ${id}`);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="test">
  Some parent wrapper
  <button type="button">Click me</button>
</div>
```